# Why is my button_to creating blank entries? Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

**Updated not using `params` but passing params into the block**

It seems like my parameters are not getting passed into the controller action. I'm trying to create an entry into the `svc_tickets` table using `button_to`.

**I'm only getting blank entries into the table**.

This is the `button_to`

```
<td class='create_service_ticket' style="width: 7%"><%= button_to 'Create Service Ticket',
                                                                          {controller: :svc_tickets,
                                                                           action: 'create',
                                                                           priority_level: 3,
                                                                           summary: event[:signature_name].to_s,
                                                                           description: 'description',
                                                                           closed: 0} %> </td>
```

`SvcTicktsController`

```
  def create
    @svc_ticket = SvcTicket.new(params[:svc_ticket])
    respond_to do |format|
      if @svc_ticket.save
        format.html { redirect_to :back, notice: 'Svc ticket was successfully created.' }
        #format.json { render json: @svc_ticket, status: :created, location: @svc_ticket }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @svc_ticket.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

This is from the page source

```
  <form action="/svc_tickets?closed=0&amp;description=description&amp;priority_level=3&amp;summary=drop+-+WP-Admin+attempt" class="button_to" method="post">
    <div>
      <input type="submit" value="Create Service Ticket">
      <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="qWjFT8JDEUPXceQN3taodnInwerVEiCIKayJKBoEoTs=">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: have you tried this `params:{ svc_ticket: {priority_level: 3, summary: event[:signature_name].to_s, description: 'description', closed: 0}}`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails link\_to or button\_to post request with parameters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12360148/rails-link-to-or-button-to-post-request-with-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is not implemented in Rails 3. Look at specification of this method [here](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.13/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/button_to). It was implemented in Rails 4.

Answer (score 0):

As [explained in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.21/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) the second parameter to `button_to` in Rails 3 is the options hash that is passed to `url_for`, so it's that second parameter where you pass your `params`:

```
button_to('Create Service Ticket', {
  controller: :svc_tickets,
  params: {
    priority_level: 3,
    summary: event[:signature_name].to_s,
    description: 'description',
    closed: 0
  }
})
```