# wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

### What I'm trying to do

I'm trying to `each do` over a table to create a new relationship.

The rules are as follows:

- A user creates events
- An event can have many guests(users)

I want `current_user` as per devise gem to be able to join events.

### What I tried

```
class AttendingEventsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @attending_event = AttendingEvent.new
  end

  def join event_id
    @attending_event = @attending_event.new(user_id: current_user.id, event_id: event_id)
  end
end
```

When joining the event via the `join` method as user I'm getting the wrong arguments error.

My button looks like this:

```
<% Event.all.each do |e| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= e.title %></td>
        ...
        <td><%= button_to "join event", join_path e.id, method: :get %></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

Routes file for reference:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'welcome/home'
  get 'events/all'
  get 'users/index'

  get '/join', to: 'attending_events#join', as: 'join'


  resources :users do
    resources :events
  end

  root 'welcome#home'
end
```

Comment: Try `button_to "smth", some_path, method: :get, params: { start_point: 3.month.ago }` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/39952571/5239030)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that your routes would look something more like (I don't think you need to nest it under `users`):

```
resources :events do 
  member do 
    get :join
  end
end
```

Which will give you:

```
join_event GET    /events/:id/join(.:format)                             events#join
    events GET    /events(.:format)                                      events#index
           POST   /events(.:format)                                      events#create
 new_event GET    /events/new(.:format)                                  events#new
edit_event GET    /events/:id/edit(.:format)                             events#edit
     event GET    /events/:id(.:format)                                  events#show
           PATCH  /events/:id(.:format)                                  events#update
           PUT    /events/:id(.:format)                                  events#update
           DELETE /events/:id(.:format)                                  events#destroy
```

Then, in your `EventsController`, do:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    # I don't know if you need this, based on the code you posted
    @attending_event = AttendingEvent.new
  end

  def join
    @event = Event.find(params[:id])
    @attending_event = current_user.attending_events.new(event: @event)
    if @attending_event.save
      #do something
    else
      #do something else
    end
  end

end
```

This assumes that:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  has_many :attending_events
end
```

And:

```
class AttendingEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :event
end
```

Then in your view:

```
<% Event.all.each do |e| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= e.title %></td>
    ...
    <td><%= button_to "join event", join_event_path(e), method: :get %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Error is gone, however `sqlite> Select count(*) from attending_events;` returns 
`0` even though the join button triggered `join`.  Which is understandable, since I don't pass parameters on anymore. Still, it's not working.

Comment: I adjusted according to your recommendations, however I get `undefined method `join_event_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f96bc84af58>:0x007f96bb4aa408>`

Comment: Did you update your `routes.rb`? If you do `rake routes` in your console, you can see your available routes and their names.

Comment: According to what you felt should be in there. It produced the error. Feel free to check out [the feature branch on Github](https://github.com/BlkPingu/attendion/tree/0009/attend_events). I just pushed the changes. I know this is kind of blatant, but I feel like we're missing something here.

Comment: In your `routes.rb`, you do `users do`. It should be `member do`.

Comment: Changed that, getting `The action 'join' could not be found for EventsController` even though it's clearly there.

Comment: The `join` action is not in the version you linked to, above. Also, I question why you're doing all that `@user = User.find(params[:user_id])` when you're using Devise. Why aren't you just using `current_user`? (Unless the current user can sign someone else up, I suppose.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181245/discussion-between-jvillian-and-tobias-kolb).